# Change a specific button in a grid

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I'm using this to define a grid of buttons.  I want to programmatically change the attribute of a specific button, like:

```
if(button.tag == 6)
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:imageRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:imageRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Button creation below.

---

```
for (int y=0; y < 3; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        //button.frame = CGRectMake(40 + 80 * x, 40 + 80 * y, 80, 80);

        button.frame=CGRectMake(5+5*x,5+5*y,5,5);

        unsigned buttonNumber = y * 3 + x + 1;
        button.tag = buttonNumber;
        //[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", buttonNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:imageWhite forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:imageWhite forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview: button];
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused on how to label the buttons as they are just created there.  Do I need to add UIButton button1, button2, to buttonN and wire them in.  It will get messy as I want to make the grid larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but it seems like 'how do I find a view with a specific tag?'. The answer is the UIView method

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
```

This will look through the current view and all it's subviews for the specified tag and return the first view it finds that matches it. So to get, for example, the button with tag 6, just do:

```
UIView* button = [self.view viewWithTag:6];
```

Of course, when dealing with a target method, like your `buttonPressed:` method, the view that triggered the event is passed as a parameter, so you can also use that if that's the only time you need it. Other than that everything in your code looks fine.

Comment: Except now lets say I have button = [self.view viewWithTag:6];  I want to know the image that is currently set.  The button property is .currentImage  It doesn't seem to work here.  Like I want to do If button.currentImage = imageRed then set button.image = imageWhite ?

Comment: Depending on what you're setting, you may want to check `button.currentBackgroundImage` rather than `button.currentImage`. That said, `.currentImage` should work. What value does it return when you check it?

Comment: It doesn't know either property.  I assume I need to define a uibutton somehow instead of a uiview?

Comment: Maybe something like this  button = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        
NSLog(@"%@\n",button.currentImage);

Comment: I ended up getting it to work using an array of buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this...

```
 for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       // [ButtonArray addObject:button];

        button.tag = row * COLS + col;

        button.frame = CGRectMake(5+5*row,5+5*col,5,5);
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didPushButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [button setBackgroundImage:imageWhite forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:imageWhite forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
        buttonArr[row*COLS+col]=button;
    }
}
```